# SQL statement to show data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables that I want to show in one query,
This structure these tables

```
1. tbl_user
+-----------+------
   userId   | name 
+-----------+------
 uid1       | jorge
 uid2       | kaka
 uid3       | victor
 uid4       | james

2. tbl_question
+-----------+--------+------------------------------------+--------------
 questionId | userId | question                           | answer_count
+-----------+--------+------------------------------------+--------------
 qid1       | uid2   | what do you think about elephant?  | 3
 qid2       | uid2   | what do you think about cat?       | 1
 qid3       | uid2   | what do you think about shark ?    | 0
 qid4       | udi3   | what do you think about snake ?    | 1

3. tbl_answer
+-----------+--------+------------------------------------+--------------
 questionId | userId | answer
+-----------+--------+------------------------------------+--------------
 qid1       | uid4   | it's have a big body
 qid1       | uid2   | it's have a long nose
 qid1       | uid1   | it's have 4feet
 qid2       | uid3   | it's a cute animal
 qid4       | uid2   | it's have a poison
```

I want to display data from all table with specified userid, so far as I use SQL statement below

```
select tbl_user.userId,name,question,answer_count,tbl_answer.userId,answer from tbl_question INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_question.userId=tbl_user.userId LEFT JOIN tbl_answer ON tbl_answer.questionId=tbl_question.questionId WHERE tb_question.userId='uid2';
```

here is the result:

```
userId | name   | questionId | question                             | answer_count | tbl_answer.userId | answer 
-------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------
 uid2  | kaka   |    qid1    | what do you think about elephant ?   |  3           |      uid4         | it's have a big body
 uid2  | kaka   |    qid1    | what do you think about elephant ?   |  3           |      uid2         | it's have a long nose
 uid2  | kaka   |    qid1    | what do you think about elephant ?   |  3           |      uid1         | it's have 4feet
 uid2  | kaka   |    qid2    | what do you think about cat   ?      |  1           |      uid3         | it's a cute animal
 uid2  | kaka   |    qid3    | what do you think about shark ?      |  0           |      null         | null
```

above results appear all the data with userid = 'uid2', but that I want results:

`tbl_answer.userId='uid2'` 
and if `tbl_answer.userId` is `null` or `tbl_answer.userId<>'uid2'` like below:

```
userId | name   | questionId | question                             | answer_count | tbl_answer.userId | answer 
-------+--------+--------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------
 uid2  | kaka   |    qid1    | what do you think about elephant ?   |  3           |      uid2         | it's have a long nose
 uid2  | kaka   |    qid2    | what do you think about cat   ?      |  1           |      uid3         | it's a cute animal
 uid2  | kaka   |    qid3    | what do you think about shark ?      |  0           |      null         | null
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: One case is still not covered. What if there is question asked by `user2` which has more than one answer and none of them is from `user2`. What should be returned then as answer?

Comment: I just tried mysql with the case, there was no data to show up, how do I handle this? I want to keep showing the null or anything in the field "tbl_answer.userId"?

Comment: Ok..i will try soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a query which solves your problem:

```
select tbl_user.userId,name,question,answer_count,tbl_answer.userId,answer 
from tbl_question 
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_question.userId=tbl_user.userId 
LEFT JOIN tbl_answer ON tbl_answer.questionId=tbl_question.questionId 
WHERE tbl_question.userId='uid2'
AND (tbl_answer.userId = 'uid2' 
     OR 
     tbl_answer.userId IS NULL 
     OR     
     (select count(questionId) from tbl_answer a where a.questionId=tbl_question.questionId and a.userId = 'uid2') = 0
     AND
     tbl_answer.userId = (select min(userId) from tbl_answer a where a.questionId=tbl_question.questionId)
)
```

It returns all the question asked by `user2`.
If `user2` is one of answerers then only his answer is returned.
If there is no answer then null is returned.
If there are only answers provided by other users than `user2` then the answer of user with miimal id is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Add to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE <...> AND (tbl_answer.userId = 'uid2' OR tbl_answer.userId IS NULL)
```

Comment: ow..thats it..run like a charm.. thaks

Comment: sory i undo acceptance.. i use sql statement above run fine, but when tbl_answer.id_a is not 'uid2' and not null sql statement doesnt work properly,,
see edit